# Dichotomous dependent and ordinal independent variable with 12 levels. SPSS

Tags: spss, logistic-regression, chi-squared

I am working on to find strength of association between binary dependent variable and ordinal independent variable(IV). I tried chi square to see the cross tabulation and clearly few categories from (IV) have more association if dependent variable(yes or no). But many cells have expected values less than 5.

I also used logistic regression however it gives me significant value such as 1.000 0.999 etc and no significant value among all the (IV)levels.

I am not sure if I am able to clearly specify my problem. I can only use SPSS!

Answer (score 0):

How did you treat the independent variable?  Just entering it as a linear predictor is not appropriate if it is ordinal scale.

You might also want to collapse categories.  A decision tree might also be useful.